# Docker-Compose Logs From Interval Process are Queued?

Tags: docker, logging, printing, docker-compose

I've got a Docker Container setup that includes two python programs running at the same time.

- Process A is a web server supported by flask that selects data from an SQLITE DB and puts it on a static page
- Process B is a program which retrieves data from a webpage, parses it, processes it (triggering SMS alerts), caches the results, stores new results in a db, and prints the processed data in a couple different ways.  Process B runs on an interval every 45 seconds within the Python program itself using a while loop like such:

```python
while True:
   # do_something
   sleep(45)
```

Both processes function perfectly fine.  *There are no errors with printing and in fact I receive real-time alerts and I can validate the timestamps of the DB inserts are on those 45 second intervals.  Though the "logs" from `docker-compose up` seem to be queued.  At times there will be no movement and then suddenly an hour's worth of print statements are generated?*

The docker container is running on a Raspberry Pi 3+ (Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS) and using `htop` I can see that the container barely registers 0.1% CPU usage and about 3.4% memory usage.

My version of Docker is: `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88`

---

When I access website powered by Process A it registers those logs immediately but I think this is because it is accessing the network.  I don't have any logs setup to print in Flask.

Process A and Process B are under the same service and are invoked by the script provided in the docker docs on running multiple processes:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of digging the question was already asked and answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362213/docker-compose-not-printing-stdout-in-python-app